# new image in canvas with fabric js doesn't work for chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas, fabricjs

I use fabric.js to manage my canvas, however when I make new fabric.Image after dropped a picture in my canvas it's doesn't work in chrome!

there is my code :

```
var imgElement = document.getElementById(idImageToDrage);

var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
    id: parseInt(idImageToDrage),
    left: calculPositionLeft, // position when I drop the picture
    top: calculPositionTop,
    scaleX: 0.147,
    scaleY: 0.147,
    angle: 0,
    zindex: $('#containerInnerImgToDrag').children().length,
    name: 'img'
});

imgInstance.setControlsVisibility({ 'bl': false, 'br': false, 'mb': false, 'ml': false, 'mr': false, 'mt': false, 'tl': false, 'tr': false });
canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

This code work for Firefox, what can I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: you are dropping image from outside or from same window?

Comment: I have 2 containers, one is where I have all my picture and the seconde is my canvas like: `1<div>Pictures</div>2<canvas></canvas>`

Comment: Looks like you are doing weird stuff with `idImageToDrage`.

Comment: `idImageToDrage` is set before

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/w8kkc/414/)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 My image is juste not drawing, she disappears

Comment: Why `id: parseint(idImageToDrage)` on new fabric object?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 because I save position but this part of code works !

Comment: @Durga I use Jquery draggable for my pictures and droppable for my canvas !

Comment: Make a minimal snippet / fiddle.

Comment: @Durga https://jsfiddle.net/cd15m3mv/3/

Comment: @rem some error are there, care to fix it ;)

Comment: @Durga https://jsfiddle.net/cd15m3mv/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
var objectDropped = ui.draggable[0];

var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(objectDropped, {
```

Dropped image element as source for fabric image.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/cd15m3mv/16/)